# How do I find first derivative to this function? (function inside function with ln)

Tags: functions, derivatives

I have stumbled upon a problem that I can't solve and I am confused what to do and what rules to implement. I want to find first derivative to $b(x)$.

Lets say we have a function $$ a(x) = \ln\left( \frac{x}{(2x-1)^2} \right) $$

How do I find first derivative to $b(x)$, when $$ b(x) =a(x)^3 $$

Comment: Do you know how to use the product rule of composite functions?

Comment: You can differentiate the expression inside the parenthesis, but in this case it is much easier to use the computation rules on logarithms to decompose...

Comment: @MattiP. ow thank you, just a follow up if I understand it correctly will it be 3 * a(x)^2 * a(x)' ?

Comment: @JacksonShaw Yes, it looks correct.